# Making different random numbers

Tags: javascript, random, operators

My function is working fine but needs to return 6 different random numbers, and eventually returns a pair of similar numbers. I tried to make it pass a simple condition if / else to run. If it doesn t pass, it is called again until the condition is satisfied.
Any suggestios how else to make sure my random function returns 6 different random numbers?

```js
const randomNum = function() {  

  var al1, al2, al2, al4, al5, al6;
  function ran() {
    al1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*60)+1);
    al2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*60)+1);
    al3 = Math.floor((Math.random()*60)+1);
    al4 = Math.floor((Math.random()*60)+1);
    al5 = Math.floor((Math.random()*60)+1);
    al6 = Math.floor((Math.random()*60)+1);  
  }

    ran()    

  
    if(al1 != al2 || al2 != al3 ||  al3 != al4 || al4 != al5 || al5 != al6) {

       //do my code

    } else {

      ran()      
    }          
  }
```

Comment: Thks so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

To generate 6 unique random numbers and store them to an array, you can simply do this:

```js
const randomNum = function() {  

 var arr = [];
 while(arr.length < 6){
   var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*60)+1);
   if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
 }
 console.log(arr);
   
}

randomNum()
```

Comment: That works super well. Many many thanks!!!